# GBQ previous month

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to pull all days for previous month however my below query only pulls last month’s same day. Is this possible? Thanks for the help!

```
select *
FROM
(TABLE_DATE_RANGE([BI_UU_HH.CID_BKID_AID_Raw_],
TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"Month")),
TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(),-1,"Month"))))
```

Results:
Date
2016-07-30

Desired Results:
Whole month of July

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_QUERY([BI_UU_HH],
"REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, 'CID_BKID_AID_Raw_' + REPLACE(LEFT(STRING(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'MONTH')), 7), '-', ''))")
```

See [TABLE_QUERY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#table-query) for more details

OR

slightly modified version (still in Legacy SQL) with use of [STRFTIME_UTC_USEC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#strftime_utc_usec) function instead of string manipulation

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_QUERY([BI_UU_HH],
"REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, 'CID_BKID_AID_Raw_' + STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'MONTH'), '%Y%m'))")
```

Answer (score 3):

Using standard SQL (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" in Options):

```
SELECT *
FROM
`BI_UU_HH.CID_BKID_AID_Raw_*`
WHERE
  SUBSTR(_table_suffix, 0, 6) =
  FORMAT_DATE("%E4Y%m", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```